# ngPreserveWhitespaces doesn't work (Angular 15/17)

Tags: css, angular, templates, whitespace

Read about preserving whitespaces in Angular: https://angular.io/api/core/Component#preserving-whitespace

But for some reason I can't preserve them in template using ngPreserveWhitespaces
Even when addidng `preserveWhitespaces: true` doesn't change a thing.

here's stackblitz example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gaal3c?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It's preserved. Just inspect html

Comment: exactly, it is the browser which shows reduced whitespaces

Comment: try this `<div ngPreserveWhitespaces>This &nbsp; &nbsp; is &nbsp; &nbsp; words</div>`

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect element that text and double click it you will see that the white spaces are not actually removed, as to why your not able to visibly see the spaces, is because of CSS.

### [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

#### normal (default)

> **Sequences of white space are collapsed**. Newline characters in the source are handled the same as other white space. Lines are broken as
> necessary to fill line boxes.

Ways to stop the collapsing, you can set the white-space property to use any of the below styles where `Spaces and tabs` is set to `preserve` (for example: `pre`)

| **white space style** | **New lines** | **Spaces and tabs** | **Text wrapping** | **End-of-line spaces** | **End-of-line other space separators** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **normal** | Collapse | Collapse | Wrap | Remove | Hang |
| **nowrap** | Collapse | Collapse | No wrap | Remove | Hang |
| **pre** | Preserve | Preserve | No wrap | Preserve | No wrap |
| **pre-wrap** | Preserve | Preserve | Wrap | Hang | Hang |
| **pre-line** | Preserve | Collapse | Wrap | Remove | Hang |
| **break-spaces** | Preserve | Preserve | Wrap | Wrap | Wrap |

ts

```
import 'zone.js';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <div ngPreserveWhitespaces style="white-space: pre">
    whitespaces   are    preserved                here
    <span>    and here </span>
</div>
    <div ngPreserveWhitespaces style="white-space: break-spaces">
    whitespaces   are    preserved                here
    <span>    and here </span>
</div>
  `,
  preserveWhitespaces: true,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zpsuoj?file=src%2Fmain.ts)